# sorted insert into a fixed sized array with duplication

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, sorting, embedded

I am trying to find the most efficient C program to store N largest values from a stream of incoming data. Eg. Assume that the incoming data is 32bytes each and is a continuous stream from a sensor, I need to store the N largest values (duplicates allowed) from the stream.
The simple approach would be to iterate and find the position and then move all the elements below by one (potentially discarding the current smallest value).  Is there a better way of doing this?

[Source](https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=bitbucket&continue=https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?redirectCount=1&next=%252Fderosier%252F12bit_sort%252Fsrc%252F7d3319882f66%253Fat%253Dmaster)

```
//MAX_KEEP    32


typedef struct accel_sys
{
    FILE *infile;

    /* Data for largest and last */
    u32 largest[MAX_KEEP]; /* largest in highest index, smallest in lowest index */
    u32 last[MAX_KEEP]; /* circular buffer */
    u8 last_start; /* points to the oldest value */

    /* Data for reading and processing the file */
    u8 last_byte;
    Bool even;
    int num_read;

} accel_t;

typedef accel_t * accel_h;
static void store_max(accel_h accel, u32 cur_value)
{
    int i = MAX_KEEP-1;
    int j = 0;

    while(i >= 0)
    {
        if( cur_value > accel->largest[i] )
        {
            /* found it */
            
            break;
        }
        i--;
    }

    /* i < 0 if the value doesn't belong in the array, do nothing in that case */
    if( i >= 0 )
    {
        /* Move everything lower than cur_value down, losing the last value,
         * then store our new value in our found spot */
        j = 0;
        while( j < i )
        {
            accel->largest[j] = accel->largest[j+1];
            j++;
        }
        accel->largest[i] = cur_value;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is reasonable. There are other data structures that might be more suitable for your needs., but if you are strictly looking to use an array you could rid yourself of needing to iterate to shift and do a memmove instead. `memmove(accel, accel + 1, i);`

Comment: If the incoming data is 32 bytes each, storing it in a `u16` may not be the best idea…

Comment: Do the values fit into a range that could be 'categorized' into a smaller range like {small, medium, large} or something of that sort? Is there a fairly balanced distribution like that or could it be very skewed towards one side?

If the distribution is fairly balanced, one simple optimization is to store K arrays representing this smaller range (ex: 3 buckets) using a hash. This is somewhat akin to radix sorting. Your same basic insertion sort algorithm would still apply, but only within each bucket.

Comment: If data was indeed `32bytes each`, the difference in misfit between u16 and u32 was negligible. Then again, for one single sensor reading, 32 *bits* isn't mean, and 32 bytes a load even in "readable ASCII".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optimization is to replace your explicit loop for shifting the array with a `memmove`. Of course either way it's linear time, but on most platforms, `memmove` is linear with a much faster constant multiplier.

---

Next, how big is N? Because you're apparently already keeping the values in sorted order, so, why not do a bisect search instead of a linear search? This means that your amortized average time becomes O(log N) instead of O(N).<sup>*</sup>

So (untested; I guarantee at least one off-by-one error somewhere…):

```
static void store_max(accel_h accel, uint16_t cur_value) {
    size_t first = 0, last = N, middle;
    while (first < last) {
        middle = (first + last)/2;
        if (accel->largest[middle] < cur_value)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (accel->largest[middle] == cur_value)
            break;
        else
            last = middle - 1;
    }
    if (middle > 0) {
        memmove(accel->largest, accel->largest+1, middle);
        accel->largest[middle] = cur_value;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to improve worst-case time, you want a heap, because you can push-pop in logarithmic time.<sup>**</sup> And you can store a heap in a plain old array of N values just like your sorted array, and read out the values in sorted order in linear time. But that adds some more complexity, and I don't want to try to write the code on my phone. :)

---

<sub>* Your worst case is still O(N); imagine a pathological case where the values just keep increasing. But even in that case, a very fast O(N) + a slow O(log N) maybe a worthwhile improvement over a very fast O(N) + a slow O(N).</sub>

<sub>** Although in practice, O(log N) swaps may be slower than a `memmove` for the values of `N` you probably care about…</sub>